# WP Admin bar hidden on front-end?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, toolbar, user-roles

I am using a function to hide the WP admin bar for specific users with the following code:

```
//Hide admin bar for subscribers
if (current_user_can('subscriber') || !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // user can't view admin bar
    show_admin_bar(false);
}
else {
    show_admin_bar(true);
}
```

It works for `subscribers` and `visitors` but when logged in as an `administrator` the admin bar doesn't show up on the front-end. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

SOLUTION: The code above here works

Comment: In which function you are applying this code?

Comment: I just pasted this into my `function.php` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
//Hide admin bar for subscribers
if( current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('visitor') ) {
  // user can't view admin bar
  show_admin_bar(false);
} else {
  show_admin_bar(true);
}
```

---

**Updated Code:**

```
//Hide admin bar for all users except administrators
if( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
  show_admin_bar(true);
} else {
  // All other users can't view admin bar
  show_admin_bar(false);
}
```

Comment: With this function the admin bar appears for visitors

Comment: Looks like the issue with the visitor role you have created. also, the hook "after_setup_theme" doesn't look the right. you can remove that and put the code directly from if the condition or change the hook.

Comment: That's what I thought too but how to fix it haha

Comment: I changed my code but the result is the same. Should I work with `!is_user_logged_in()` ?

Comment: Changed my code to what it is now and looks like this is the solution ;)

Comment: With your code you can choose per user what they can see?

Comment: The updated code will enable the admin bar for admin users only.

Answer (score 1):

Use `show_admin_bar` filter to hide/display the admin bar.

```
/**
 * Checks if the user belongs to the roles.
 * 
 * @param int/WP_User $user Either user_id or WP_User object.
 * @param string/string[] $roles Single roles or array of roles.
 */
function is_user_in_role($user, $roles ) {
    // Set user_id to null;
    $user_obj = null;

    // Check if the $user is integer.
    if ( is_int( $user ) ) {
        $user_obj = get_user_by( 'id', $user );
    }

    // Check if the $user is object.
    if ( $user instanceof WP_User) {
        $user_obj = $user;
    }

    // Bail if the $user_id is not set.
    if ( null === $user_obj) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if the user belons to the role.
    if ( is_string( $roles ) ) {
        return in_array( $roles, (array) $user_obj->roles );
    }

    // Check if the user belongs to the roles.
    if ( is_array( $roles ) ) {
        $user_belong_to = true;
        foreach( $roles as $role ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $role, (array) $user_obj->roles ) ) {
                $user_belong_to = false;
            }
        }
        return $user_belong_to;
    }

    // Return false if nothing works.
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar' );
function hide_admin_bar() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( is_user_in_role($user, 'administrator' ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://cpothemes.com/disable-wordpress-admin-bar

Answer (score 0):

Check that **Show Toolbar when viewing site** is checked in your user settings.